# How do I switch between Entry fields using the up and down keys in Tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

It seems to work as it should, but when the focus moves to the last input field, after pressing the "down" key, an error occurs - "IndexError: list index out of range", although it should jump back to the topmost widget. With the "up" button, everything works as it should. Guys, who can tell me how to fix it?

```
import tkinter as tk


def downKey(event):
    handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    lstHandle[lstHandle.index(handle) + 1].focus()

def upKey(event):
    handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    lstHandle[lstHandle.index(handle) - 1].focus()


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("500x500+500+200")


win.bind('<Down>', downKey)
win.bind('<Up>', upKey)

lstHandle = []

ent1 = tk.Entry()
lstHandle.append(ent1)
ent1.place(x=196,y=5)

ent2 = tk.Entry()
lstHandle.append(ent2)
ent2.place(x=196,y=30)

ent3 = tk.Entry()
lstHandle.append(ent3)
ent3.place(x=196,y=55)

ent4 = tk.Entry()
lstHandle.append(ent4)
ent4.place(x=196,y=80)

ent5 = tk.Entry()
lstHandle.append(ent5)
ent5.place(x=196,y=105)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you can try to make a condition check before calling `.focus()`
the error is literally telling you that the `lstHandle` index is out of range.
There are only 5 elements in the list but you called `thelist[5]`, ofcourse it will cause error

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the *modulo* operator (`%`) to get the correct index:

```py
def downKey(event):
    handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    lstHandle[(lstHandle.index(handle) + 1)%len(lstHandle)].focus()

def upKey(event):
    handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    lstHandle[(lstHandle.index(handle) - 1)%len(lstHandle)].focus()
```

Another way is simply using `.tk_focusNext()` and `.tk_focusPrev()`:

```py
def downKey(event):
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()

def upKey(event):
    event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus()
```

Comment: Ooh that option with `tk_focusNext()` and `tk_focusPrev()` is quite elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code you specifically define what should happen when you press <kbd>up</kbd> on the first or <kbd>down</kbd> on the last entry.

For going up, this seems to work by accident due to how python list indexing works. When you press <kbd>up</kbd> on the first widget, `lstHandle.index(handle)` equals `0`, so `lstHandle.index(handle) - 1` equals `-1`. In python, using `-1` as the index for a list returns the last item in the list, which is why the last widget gets the focus.

For going down, when you press <kbd>down</kbd> on the last widget `lstHandle.index(handle)` equals `4` since you have 5 widgets in your list. `lstHandle.index(handle) + 1` therefore equals `5`. However, for a list of length 5, `list[5]` does not exist since there is no sixth item in the list. To loop back to the first widget, you can manually check if the current widget is the last one and return to index 0 if it is using something like

```
def downKey(event):
    handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    index = lstHandle.index(handle) + 1
    if index == len(lstHandle):
        index = 0
    lstHandle[index].focus()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now I understand what my mistake is. Now I will know!